# how to add text in grid view end

Tags: android, gridview

I am using gridview for displaying images. Initially I am displaying 16 images in the gridview and next I want to display 32 images in the gridview.

I want a next button at the bottom of the grid view to go to the next set of images.

How can I set button at the bottom of a gridview for Android?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you might want to look into just dynamically loading as the user scrolls. As a user I can't friggen stand have to page through stuff and scroll. Pick one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a "button" at the bottom of the GridView, here is the layout that you have to design in your loading XML file.

```
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:numColumns="3" >
    </GridView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

For lesser grids it will be OK. If your have grids more than that your screen can show, you will get a display like this ([click here](http://twitpic.com/7hpks4))

Now you can write for the OnClickListner of the button.

BUT what I am suggesting you is, use a customize menu to put that button. Then you don't have any overlapping issue if there are so many grid items in your Activity.

Good luck